# Extract text from p only if preceding header exists using Beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I want to extract the text in paragraph element using beautifulsoup.
The html looks something like this:

```
<span class="span_class>
 <h1>heading1</h1>
 <p>para1</p>
 <h1>heading 2</h1>
 <p>para2</p>
</span>
```

I want to extract text from first p only if h1 exists and so on;
So far i have tried

```
x=soup.findAll('span',{'class':'span_class'})
y=x.findAll('p')[0].text
```

But i am not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS sibling selector here:

```
paragraphs = x.select('h1 + p')
# `paragraphs` now contains two elements: <p>para1</p> and <p>para2</p>
```

This will select only those P elements that have immediate H1 siblings before them.
If you want to do some more logic based on H1 content, you can do this:

```
for p x.select('h1:first-child + p'):
    # `p` contains the element that has `H1` before it.
    # `p.previous_sibling` contains `H1`.
    if p.previous_sibling.text == 'heading1':
        # We got the `P` that has `H1` with content `"heading1"` before it.
        print(p, p.previous_sibling)
```

Comment: how do i specify what text h1 must have? inside span there can be multiple <h1> tags

Comment: My snippet will give you all P elements that have H1 before them. If you want to filter the result by their corresponding H1 properties, e. g. contents, you'll need Python here - CSS cannot select based on tag value.

Comment: As per my need, there are multiple h1 tags, i would have to shortlist them based on the text inside; i have edited the question above as well

Comment: @separ1 do you want to extract text from all of the `P`s that have `H1` before them or only the first one? (I've updated my answer)

Comment: I want to extract p text only from the h1 containing "heading 1" as text

Comment: is there any way to specify something like: "if h1 contains "heading1" then take the next sibling?

Comment: @separ1 unfortunately that has to be done with Python. You can still use my code to find the `P` elements that have `H1` before them, but you'll need to iterate through them and compare their content to choose the right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '''<html>
<body>
<span class='span_class'>
<h1>heading1</h1>
<p>content1</p>
<p>content2</p>
<h1>heading2</h1>
<p>content3</p>
</span>
</body>
</html>'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
x = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'span_class'}) #find span
try: 
    for y in x:
        heading = y.find_all('h1') # find h1
        for something in heading:  # if h1 exist
            if something.text == 'heading1':
                print(something.text)  # print h1
                try:
                    p = something.find_next('p') #try find next p
                    print(p)
                except:                 # if no next <p>, do nothing 
                    pass
            else:
                pass                    #if is is not 'heading1', do nothing
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Is this what you are looking for? It will try to look for your `<span>` and try to find `<h1>` from it. For `<h1>` is in `<span>` , it will look for the next `<p>`.

Comment: Note that i import BeautifulSoup as bs